# When typing out ALT + ### symbols an unwanted symbol is printed also

Tags: batch-file, echo, symbols

https://i.stack.imgur.com/55GL5.png

Basically, the code on the left is suppose to echo 2 symbols as set from their variables. When you use the ° and ², they are printed as the corresponding box symbols. But, there is a third symbol that always appears when I try to use them. They always start at the beginning of the line.

I am using notepad++

Comment: Try Encoding -> Convert to ANSI

Comment: Thank you that worked :)

Comment: That's good. Posted an answer for completeness' sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your batch file is probably encoded in UTF8, and therefore the ° and ² symbols are being represented by two bytes each.

The command interpreter apparently expects the file is ANSI encoded - one byte per character, for every character.

You can convert the file to ANSI with Notepad++ using the `Encoding` -> `Convert to ANSI` menu option.